# Is there a way to install mongodb-tools on debian11 on arm64

Tags: mongodb, docker, debian, mongodb-tools

I need to use a Docker image based on Debian 11, that runs on a Macbook M1 so on ARM64.
In the Mongo download centre
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/bi-connector
at "MongoDB Command Line Database Tools Download"
there is no option for Debian-ARM64, only x86_64
Is it possible? Any alternatives?

Thanks

**Tried**.
In Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget -nv https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-arm64-100.7.0.deb && \
apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y ./mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-arm64-100.7.0.deb && \
rm ./mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-arm64-100.6.1.deb
```

**GOT**

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
mongodb-database-tools:arm64 : 
Depends: libc6:arm64 but it is not installable. 
                                
Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:arm64 but it is not installable. 
                                
Depends: libkrb5-3:arm64 but it is not installable. 
                                
Depends: libk5crypto3:arm64 but it is not installable. 
                                
Depends: libcomerr2:arm64 but it is not installable. 
                                
Depends: libkrb5support0:arm64 but it is not installable. 
                                
Depends: libkeyutils1:arm64 but it is not installable. 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Worst case you could build from source. Pretty straightforward: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.asc | gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg --dearmor \
    && echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```